# How to adjust for variable?

Tags: r, model, regression, cluster-computing

I have a question that I am stuck on.

I am doing my data analysis, but there is a variable that I have to adjust to hold constant, before I run my linear model. The variable is location where I selected participant from, so adjusting for this variable is a MUST.

Does anyone know what code should I use on R? Or how to even do it in the first place!

Thanks!

Comment: Try posting a *minimal reproducible example* to give people an idea of what you want to do and where you are stuck in your code. See https://community.rstudio.com/t/faq-how-to-do-a-minimal-reproducible-example-reprex-for-beginners/23061

Comment: As your question is about R, I've removed the `stata` tag.